# Yahoo mail recipient (To) field problem when pressing ALT+@

Tags: yahoo-mail, keyboard-shortcuts

When I want to send an e-mail in Yahoo mail, and I want to enter recipient's e-mail address, I have a problem. When I come to the the point when I need to insert `@` sign and I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> on a keyboard to do so, an e-mail address instantly becomes highlighted as it was finished with the `@` sign, and I can't enter the rest of it. This happens every time and is quite annoying, especially when I have several recipients and the only solution for me is to enter a full address in the text field below and then copy it to the recipient field.

I went through all the settings of my Yahoo account and I don't seem to find something to correct it. That hasn't been happening since maybe a year ago, I haven't changed anything with my Yahoo mail account in the meantime, and I also used Mozilla Firefox before. It just started happening. I suppose that the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> is somewhere defined as something that finalises an e-mail address, but I can't figure out what to do to change it. So if anyone can help with some advice, it would be great.

Comment: What browsers have you tried? Does this happen in every browser?

Comment: It happens both in Firefox and in Chrome. I can then either double-click on an address to correct it (enter it fully with the rest of it following @ sign), or copy-paste it from somewhere else like I mentioned. I've tried pressing only alt+@ on the keyboard without anything else in "To" field and the @ sign instantly turns red.

Comment: One way is to disable javascript, this way you can "+" besides your "To" input label.